# This is a code that I followed in a YouTube video and it doesn't work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YgaLKrSApWM) YouTube tutorial code up to 11:55 in it and did exactly everything but I'm getting two errors:

> The name 'Move' does not exist in the current context and method must have a return type.

This is the code for blend tree to move the character with animation:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Animator _animator;



    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        _animator = GetComponent<Animator>();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (_animator == null) return;

        var x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        var y = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Move(x, y);
    }
    private Move(float x, float y)
    {
        _animator.SetFloat("VelX", x);
        _animator.SetFloat("VelY", y);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO, most people do not want to watch the tutorial, so, please explain what exactly it is that is not working.  Note VelX and VelY need to be float parameters in your animator, please show what you made.

Comment: As @BugFinder mentioned you need to give more info. But an obvious error is `private Move(float x, float y)` needs to have a return type, so something like `private void Move(float x, float y)`

Answer (score 6):

Change this line

```
private Move(float x, float y)
```

to look like

```
private void Move(float x, float y)
```

The problem is that you haven't specified a return type for the method.